# How to get an access query into excel vba as a range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

OK so I have this function which queries a database using a query string that I pass to it.
At the moment it outputs the query result in the worksheet.
How do I just get the function to give me the result as a range that I can use in VBA to perform calculations etc? How would I then reference this range? E.g. to get the "Name" column in the result.

```
Function Access_Data(query As String)
 'Requires reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects xx Library

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection, Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim MyConn, sSQL As String

Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, c As Long
Dim MyField, Location As Range

 'Set destination
Set Location = Sheets(1).Range("a1")
 'Set source
MyConn = "S:\Docs\Harry\Engine Client\Engine3.accdb"
 'Create query
sSQL = query

 'Create RecordSet
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
With Cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MyConn
    Set Rs = .Execute(sSQL)
End With

 'Write RecordSet to results area
Rw = Location.Row
Col = Location.Column
c = Col
Do Until Rs.EOF
    For Each MyField In Rs.Fields
        Cells(Rw, c) = MyField
        c = c + 1
    Next MyField
    Rs.MoveNext
    Rw = Rw + 1
    c = Col
Loop
Set Location = Nothing
Set Cn = Nothing
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Access_Data(query As String)
 'Requires reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects xx Library

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection, Rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim MyConn, sSQL As String

Dim Rw As Long, c As Long
Dim MyField, Result

 'Set source
MyConn = "S:\Docs\Harry\Engine Client\Engine3.accdb"
 'Create query
sSQL = query

 'Create RecordSet
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
With Cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open MyConn
    Set Rs = .Execute(sSQL)
End With

 'Write RecordSet to results
Redim Result(1 To Rs.RecordCount, 1 To Rs.Fields.Count)
Rw = 1
Do Until Rs.EOF
    c = 1
    For Each MyField In Rs.Fields
        Result(Rw, c) = MyField
        c = c + 1
    Next MyField
    Rs.MoveNext
    Rw = Rw + 1
Loop
Set Cn = Nothing

Access_Data = Result
End Function
```

This will return a multi-dimension array. A range must refer to some portion of a worksheet: you cannot create an "invisible" range. (Though you can make a portion of a worksheet invisible, if that's what you're after.)

To access the results:

```
Dim v, i As Long
v = Access_Data("select ID, Name from somewhere")
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    MsgBox v(i, 1) & " / " & v(i, 2)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I'm after. So if I want to access the  array how would I do so? Say my query returns 2 columns: ID and Name. How do I loop through the 2 columns of data in a vba script?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I assume the columns will be in the array in the order they called in the query. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I have tried your example and vba gives me an "out of memory" error for the line when it says "Redim Result(1 to Rs.Rec.....". Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: It may happen when the number of rows in the query result is unknown: try putting `rs.MoveLast: rs.MoveFirst` before that line, to have it "preview" the result and count the rows.

Comment: It now says "rowset does not support fetching backward"

Comment: I see. Apparently it needs `.CursorLocation = adUseClient` as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Sample how to read data from SQL Server and the result insert into worksheet (here using integrated security). If the target sheet was empty before inserting new data then use UsedRange property to reference it. Or calculate it, rng is the top most left cell.

```
Option Explicit

' Add reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Lib

Public Sub main(): On Error GoTo Err_handler

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYSUPERSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYSUPERDATABASE;Integrated Security=sspi"
    cn.Open

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

    Dim fld As ADODB.Field
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = [a1]
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        rng.Value = fld.Name
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
    Next fld

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -rs.Fields.Count)
    rng.CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    Err_handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```