# VBA form with SQL Server 2008

Tags: forms, sql-server-2008, vba, ms-access

Kindly help on this topic

1. Through VBA form (Access project), I need to connect to SQL Server 2008 and load the tables (or connection).
2. I need to generate some reports (query written inside in the VBA from) against the tables in the VBA form.

Please refer to any tutorials to start this task. If this question already exists in the forum please provide link.

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards,
Bala

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857795/how-to-get-an-access-query-into-excel-vba-as-a-range/12859374#12859374. There is used Excel, but the VBA code which connects to SQL server via ADO might be the same.

Comment: This is the code i am looking for , i can modify it . Thanks a lot Daniel :)

Comment: @DanielDusek Access is *not* like Excel in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect the tables using the Access wizards for connecting external tables. The SQL Server tables can then be easily manipulated for forms and reports. http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s285/linkviewsvba.htm) shows how to link a table with VBA.  Most likely you will want a table of table names so that your code can loop through and create or refresh the links or even set them to a different instance of SQL Server.  The link shows more ways of linking but if the SQL Server table has a primary key this code will work.  Here is the code from this link.

```
' Some variable to make the code more generic
Dim strConnectionString As String
Dim strNameInAccess As String
Dim strNameInSQLServer As String
' set the connection string
strConnectionString = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server; " & _
"SERVER=.\SQLExpress;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
' specify the tables you want to link. The table can be
' known by a different name in Access than the name in SQL server
strNameInAccess = "tblYacht"
strNameInSQLServer = "tblSailingBoat"
' delete the table from the local database if it exists
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table " & strNameInAccess
On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
strConnectionString, acTable, strNameInSQLServer, strNameInAccess
```